# How I get the Value of a Column with a Datarow object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, console, dataset

hi i read the article of DataSet in mscn and I test it step by step in a console application. First I want to get a Column value of my Database.

For testing I create a test database in my xampp and connect it about a type dataset in my application with the connection configuration. it works fine. My Problem is that I create two values in my mysql database and I want a refresh or somethink that I can see my values. or I make a error in code.

here my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (db_testDataSet data = new db_testDataSet())
            {
                DataTable artikel = data.artikel;

                GetData(artikel, "Artikel_Name");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }


        }

        private static void GetData(DataTable table,string columnname) 
        {
            DataRow[] rows = table.Select();

            foreach (var item in rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item[columnname].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: nothing i dont get data ...but in my database are two values

Comment: We probably need to see the code for `db_testDataSet`

Comment: i make it with the configuration tool of visual studio